# mkvmerge linux- how to batch split video files?

Tags: linux, split

i'm using mkvmerge for split my video files with this batch code:

```
for %%a in ("*.mp4") do "C:\Program Files (x86)\MKVToolNix\mkvmerge.exe" -o ""F:\otpt\%(title)s.%(ext)s"\%%a" --split duration:840s "%%a"
pause
```

how to use same command on linux?

Answer (score 1):

Ok.My problem is solved with this bash script.

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in *.mp4
do
    i="${i%.mp4}"
    mkvmerge -o "$i.mkv" "$i.mp4" --split duration:600s
done
```